# How to get the financial years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have requirement where is need to get financial years staring from 2019 to current year,

Output required:

```
2019-2020
2020-2021
2021-2022
2022-2023
```

Please find help me out with SQL query for required format.
Note: next year it should come dynamically 2023-2024.

```
SELECT @FIYear AS F_YEAR

SELECT QM_FIN_YEAR =
        CASE
            WHEN Month(GETDATE()) BETWEEN 4 AND 12
                THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE())) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1)
            WHEN Month(GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
                THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE()) )
End ORDER by 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of SQL Server this is very easy using *generate_series*

```
with years as (select value y from generate_series(2019, year(getdate()) - 1))
  
select concat_ws('-', y, y + 1) FinancialYear
from years;
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NWo2wZon)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result with below query

```
WITH cte_Years AS (
    SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())-1 AS start_year, YEAR(GETDATE()) AS end_year
    UNION ALL
    SELECT start_year-1, end_year-1
    FROM cte_Years
    WHERE start_year-1 >= 2019
)
SELECT CONCAT(start_year, '-', end_year) AS financial_year
FROM cte_Years
ORDER BY end_year
```

Comment: Thank you Mukesh Arora. Getting the required output

Comment: @anilkumar - if this query/answer works for you. You may accept the answer and/or vote, this will help others to know.